# Async/Await post request - nodejs

Tags: node.js, express

Before carrying on with the rest of my POST request I need to make a database call and wait for the response of that (in this case wait for the promise to be fulfilled).

```
app.post("/charge", (req, res) => {
  var user_stripe_id = await queries.get_stripe_id_by_email(req.body.token.email);
}
```

However I can't await the query as I'm not in an async function. How can I make `app.post` async ?

In other routes I have done this

```
app.get('/', async function (req, res) {
  const leagues = await distinctLeagues();
  res.render('home', { leagues: leagues });
});
```

But I would like to know how to do it with the arrow function syntax.

Comment: you mean like `async (req,res) => ` this ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create an `async` function in es6 as shown below:

```
app.post("/charge", async (req, res) => {
  var user_stripe_id = await queries.get_stripe_id_by_email(req.body.token.email);
}
```

Here is an ideal usage for async-await, use it inside a try-catch. Value that is resolved by the promise would be assigned to `quote` and if the promise is rejected the catch block will be executed.

```
async function main() {
  try {
    var quote = await getQuote();
    console.log(quote);
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
  }
}
```

Comment: how would i use an `await` in a `then` `.then(charge => {` for example ?

Comment: I didn't understand the question, could you elaborate.

Comment: @Richlewis you wouldn't. Don't mix `async-await` syntax with `.then()` or `.catch()`

Comment: @Richlewis Updated the answer on using try-catch with async-await